# group some properties in properties tab in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image]

I want to have some properties like this
for example I want  to have System Permission and it contains properties like SMS,Line, and ...

Comment: There are properties for each control. While it is a good idea to be able to do this, I don't think you can group selected properties in a new defined tab.

Comment: Look for [ExpandableObjectConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter), related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546919/how-to-display-object-with-sub-class-in-propertygrid/49145207

Comment: See the [Font object](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/Font.cs,33) in the .Net Source code. That's a complex object. To show its properties in the PropertyGrid, it requires a TypeConverter and a custom Editor. If your Class Object contains properties that already define a TypeConverter (as Font, or e.g., Size, Point, Rectangle), you don't need to do anything, these are already setup in the Framework. Just decorate the class Object used as the Property value with `[Serializable]` and `[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]`.

Comment: If your Class Object instead defines complex objects that are not already known and *understood* by the Framework, you need to provide your own TypeConverter(s) and, possibly, a custom Editor (which actually boils down to a simple Form that provides means to edit the properties of a *complex object*. e.g., The Font selector that is opened when you want to change or configure a `Font` Type property).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov this is for category, I need something that make node for me

Answer (score 0):

The UI here is based on the TypeDescriptor view of the object being inspected. Grouping isn't a concept, but it does support sub-objects. The easiest way to do what you want is to simply model the group's as different types, so: have a class that represents System Permission things, with properties for SMS etc. Attributes like `[DisplayName(...)]` can be used to tweak display with spaces etc. You'd then have an instance of your type as a property on the object being edited.

Everything here *can* be done without changing the model, but that requires custom type descriptors, which is hard to do and not particularly exciting. Changing the object model is qucker and easier.

Comment: well I cant find my answer but thank you for your solution

Answer (score 0):

I realize this request is for C# but thought this vb.net example would be helpful nonetheless. This shows how to group two custom properties in the designer property grid. It's tested on .net 4.8.1.

To try it, start a new vb project and add a user control called 'UserControl1'. Drop a couple of labels, 'Label1' and 'Label2' onto the user control canvas and paste the following code into the code module:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Globalization
Public Class UserControl1
    Inherits UserControl
    Private _MyProperties As New CollapsibleProperties(Me)
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Label1.Text = _MyProperties.Property1
        Label2.Text = _MyProperties.Property2
    End Sub
    <Browsable(True),
        EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
        Category("MyCategory"),
        DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public Property MyProperties() As CollapsibleProperties
        Get
            Return Me._MyProperties
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As CollapsibleProperties)
            Me._MyProperties = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
<TypeConverter(GetType(MyObjectConverter))>
Public Class CollapsibleProperties
    Private _parentControl As UserControl1
    Private _text1 As String = "String1"
    Private _text2 As String = "String2"
    Public Sub New(parentControl As UserControl1)
        _parentControl = parentControl
    End Sub
    <Browsable(True), NotifyParentProperty(True), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)>
    Public Property Property1() As String
        Get
            Return _text1
        End Get
        Set
            If _text1 <> Value Then
                _text1 = Value
                _parentControl.Label1.Text = Value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    <Browsable(True), NotifyParentProperty(True), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)>
    Public Property Property2() As String
        Get
            Return _text2
        End Get
        Set
            If _text2 <> Value Then
                _text2 = Value
                _parentControl.Label2.Text = Value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
Public Class MyObjectConverter
    Inherits ExpandableObjectConverter

    'suppress text in the value
    'cell of the parent property
    Public Overrides Function ConvertTo(ByVal context As ITypeDescriptorContext, ByVal culture As CultureInfo, ByVal value As Object, ByVal destinationType As Type) As Object
        If destinationType Is GetType(String) Then
            Return ""
        End If
        Return MyBase.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType)
    End Function
End Class
```